# Interpreting JetBrains dotMemory profile with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, resharper, dotmemory

I have an algorithm which is based upon a grid which has a two-dimensional array of grid squares and where each grid square has an array of triangles.

I have run dotMemory to profile the memory usage and noticed something which I can't explain.

Under the Dominators view I can see the Grid class which is the dominator of the 2D GridSquare array, then the GridSquare array is the dominator for GridSquare and Triangle. Here it says there are several thousand triangles. However, if I drill down further in the GridSquare, I see its triangle array, and I can then expand this and see there is another triangle node here which has about 100 triangles.

So my question is this: Why are there two triangle nodes with different quantities and is this an indication of inefficient memory usage?

Comment: This is going to be very difficult for anyone to answer as, for example, it's not even clear what technology this is in (ASP.Net?  WinForms?)  Can you edit your question to include an example of what you're doing?  Read this for details:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you please post declarations of your data structures and upload the dotMemory workspace here? ftp://ftp.intellij.net/.uploads/
Or at least share screenshot of Dominators view with clearly visible problem you described.